# What is K3-surface and Calabi-Yau metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Maybe ,this is not a good question .

I am reading some paper about Ricci flow. K3-surface with Calabi-Yau metric are refered as example of Einstein manifold. But I don't know what they are . Then I google it , and find that there are many algebraic geometry's concepts. But I know nothing about algebraic topology , for understand what they are , what I should read ?

I just have some knowledge of  Riemannian geometry , algebraic topology   and basic group ring field theory.

Comment: They are compact Kahler manifolds that admit a Ricci-flat Kahler metric. There's a nice article by Beauville you can read about them for a quick intro (Variétés Kahleriennes dont la première classe de Chern est nulle). See also the book "Einstein manifolds" by Besse.

Comment: You don't need much algebraic geometry to understand what is a [Kahler manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold). You definitely need to know a lot of PDE's to know why a compact Kahler manifold with zero first chern class admits a Ricci flat metric.

Comment: I consider Moroianu's lecturer notes (http://moroianu.perso.math.cnrs.fr/tex/kg.pdf) a very good reference.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon What is the name of Beauville's book ?

Comment: @Cla  I am reading it , I have many question ,do you have read off it ?

Comment: @JohnMa  First, I should understand the basic notion ,what I should read ?

Comment: Of course you have many questions. You need to work hard, it is a lecture note and it gives you the main ideas in the theory. Then it is your task to assimilate and understand it (through other lectures sometimes, especially for the last chapters). Andrew's answer below should supply you with other references and the leading facts and ideas. Moroianu's notes were my first introduction to this subject when I was a master student and I found it very good, it may be different with you though..

Comment: @Gunnar In this context, I don't like this as a definition of a K3 surface. K3 surfaces are serving as examples of Einstein manifolds. Any sort of Ricci-flat manifold whether compact Kähler, spin, etc. is Einstein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$Here's a quick summary of "basic cultural facts", see also [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K3+surface) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3_surface). For details, perhaps consult

- *Principles of Algebraic Geometry* by Griffiths and Harris,
- *Complex Manifolds and Deformation of Complex Structures* by Kodaira,
- *Einstein Manifolds* by Besse,
- *Lectures on Hermitian-Einstein Metrics for Stable Bundles and Kähler-Einstein Metrics* by Siu,
- *Canonical Metrics in Kähler Geometry* by Tian.

A *K3 surface* (for Kummer, Kähler, Kodaira) is a compact, simply-connected holomorphic surface with trivial canonical bundle (i.e., admitting a non-vanishing holomorphic $2$-form).

Examples of K3 surfaces include:

- A smooth quartic surface in $\Cpx\Proj^{3}$.
- A smooth surface of degree $(2, 2, 2)$ in $\Cpx\Proj^{1} \times \Cpx\Proj^{1} \times \Cpx\Proj^{1}$, i.e., the locus of a homogeneous sextic that is quadratic in the homogeneous coordinates of each projective line.
- A smooth complex surface obtained from a complex $2$-torus by quotienting out the involution $z \mapsto -z$, then blowing up the sixteen fixed points.

[Every K3 surface is Kählerian](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01393829), i.e., admits a Kähler metric (Siu). Any two smooth K3 surfaces are [deformation equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_theory#Deformations_of_complex_manifolds), hence diffeomorphic (Kodaira).

The moduli space of holomorphic structures on a K3 surface is $20$-dimensional, and admits a branched covering by a ball in $\Cpx^{20}$ (Siu). A $19$-dimensional subfamily consists of algebraic varieties. (Wikipedia has a sketch of the calculation.)

If $(M, J, \Omega)$ is a "polarized" holomorphic manifold, i.e., a Kählerian manifold with a fixed Dolbeault $(1, 1)$-class containing a Kähler form, then for every sufficiently smooth $(1, 1)$-form $\rho$ representing the first Chern class $c_{1}(M)$, there exists a Kähler form $\omega_{\rho}$ representing $\Omega$ whose Ricci form is $2\pi\rho$ (part of Yau's solution of the [Calabi conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi_conjecture)).

Particularly, since the first Chern class of a K3 surface is zero, every Kähler class on a K3 surface admits a Ricci-flat Kähler metric.

Because the holonomy of a Ricci-flat Kähler surface is contained in $SU(2) \simeq Sp(1)$, a K3 surface admits a [*hyper-Kähler structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperk%C3%A4hler_manifold), an ordered triple $I$, $J$, $K$ of holomorphic structures satisfying the quaternion identity $IJK = -1$.